# What can we use in Select Query instead of cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, cursor

I do not want to use cursor in my select query directly but I could not find any alternative ways to use.

My first query is

```
 select 'Joe' as Name,'Last' as LastName, cursor(select * from temp) as Details from dual;
```

Table Temp:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |

OUTPUT:

| Name | LastName | Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Last | {<A=1,B=2,C=3>,<A=2,B=3,C=4>,} |

I do not want to use cursor in select query directly. Is there any different usage of **"cursor(select * from temp) as details"**?

If it is possible in Declare begin end statments, it will be okay too. I am getting error when I try below way.

```
DECLARE
cursor cur is (select * from temp);
x cur%rowtype
BEGIN

open cur;
loop
fetch cur into x;
end loop;
close cur;

SELECT NAME,LASTNAME,CUR FROM DUAL;

END;
```

***Error:
Expression is of wrong type***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what do you want to get as a result?

This is what you have now:

```
SQL> select 'Joe','Last', cursor(select * from dept) as details from dual;

'JO 'LAS DETAILS
--- ---- --------------------
Joe Last CURSOR STATEMENT : 3

CURSOR STATEMENT : 3

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON


SQL>
```

Would this be OK for you?

```
SQL> select 'Joe', 'Last', d.deptno, d.dname, d.loc from dept d;

'JO 'LAS     DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
--- ---- ---------- -------------- -------------
Joe Last         10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
Joe Last         20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
Joe Last         30 SALES          CHICAGO
Joe Last         40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**: a function that returns refcursor

```
SQL> create or replace function f_temp return sys_refcursor is
  2    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4    open l_rc for select * from temp;
  5    return l_rc;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> select 'Joe','Last', f_temp
  2  from dual;

'JO 'LAS F_TEMP
--- ---- --------------------
Joe Last CURSOR STATEMENT : 3

CURSOR STATEMENT : 3

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         2          3          4


SQL>
```

Comment: Can you check the question again? I do not want to use cursor but do not want to change structure of output.

Comment: Maybe a function that returns refcursor? I edited the answer, have a look.

Comment: BTW, why do you not want to use a cursor? What's wrong it it?

Comment: You could also use `select 'Joe', 'Last', d.* from dept d` - Note, you must use an alias `d.*`

Comment: @Littlefoot there is bug in Oracle which leads to performance problem. So I need to delete it.

Comment: OK; I was just asking. Thank you for letting us know.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your cursor into `xmltype()` , for example:

```sql
select
 'Joe'
,'Last'
,xmltype (cursor(select * from temp)) as details 
from dual
```

Comment: Actually, I do not want to use cursor

Answer (score 0):

You may create a function that returns desired string to you, and then invoke the function in your SELECT

```
select 'Joe' as Name,'Last' as LastName, funcDesiredString() as Details from dual;
```

The function's logic would be something like this -

```
desiredDetails := '{';
for rec in (Select A, B, C from Temp)
Loop
 desiredDetails := desiredDetails || '<A=' || rec.A || ',B=' || rec.B || ',C=' || rec.C || '>,'; 
End Loop;
desiredDetails := TRIM(','  FROM  desiredDetails);
desiredDetails := desiredDetails || '}';
```